# Adjusting Size of Subfigure captions in Beamer

Tags: beamer, graphics, subfloats

While including two small images the caption appears to be too large.

```
\subfigure[\tiny Original]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{1.jpg}}
\subfigure[\tiny      New]{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{2.jpg}}
\caption{\tiny Image}
```

The \tiny tag works fine for the sub-caption and caption text. But the default sub-figure markers (a) and (b) appears to be too large.

How to re-size them as per text size? And i don't want to use some other package in place of subfigure now.

Comment: Please add an MWE! `sub-figure` is no known package. Thanks.

Comment: The normal way would be something like `\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}`. I guess the same can be loaded with the package `subcaption` for your subfigures. There is also `\usepackage[font=large]{subfig}` (just found that, try "tiny" and alike!). The package `subfigure` is outdated since years.

Comment: Default setting is \setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\small}

Comment: A subcaption solution: `\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{caption}{size=\tiny}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{tiny}{\tiny}
\captionsetup[sub]{font+=tiny}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}  
 \begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox{Original}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image}}
  \subcaptionbox{New}{\includegraphics[scale=0.15]{example-image}}
  \caption{Image}
 \end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}`